# Joomla 2.5 component

Tags: joomla, components, joomla2.5

Is it possible to make a 2.5 component without using `TableHelloWorld` class and all that field type stuff like from here. Or is it compulsory?

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Using_the_database

Comment: using JTable may save you on the long run quite a few of lines of code in minus, fewer bugs and easier manintainance. Even if at the beginning it may be a pain in the ass to learn it, consider that the time invested will pay out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system will function without it fairly well actually. All you actually need to get something running is a base file named after your component, a controller.php file, and the view as outlined in this section:  http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_a_view_to_the_site_part

From that you will get something that runs and loads. And if you choose you can just make raw sql queries to the database.

That being said, the framework is there to help you, not to hinder you. I've cut a lot of corners over the years, and almost always you end up regretting it later. Feel free to play around with skipping the pieces, but just remember that there are pieces out there that can help you with all kinds of important things that you may not think you need right now. (Binding input, table row hierarchies, and check-in/check-out functionality are just a few that come to mind that I'm glad I didn't have to make myself.)

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Just a question. I was following the tutorial until this part. admin/views/helloworlds/view.html.php. Why is it suddenly helloworlds instead of helloworld?

Comment: It is common on the backend to have a list view of all the items and then a form view for adding individual items. Items in this sense can be anything. So for example, when you go to the article manager, there are articles. And then you edit an article. I would guess that they are following the same format with the pluralization.